# OpenSSH folder exists in PowerShell ISE, but not in PowerShell

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, openssh

When I use PowerShell ISE, the command prompt, or even Windows Explorer, the folder: `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH` exists.

However, when I open just PowerShell as an Administrator (or not... – tried both) and try to navigate to the same folder, I can get to `C:\Windows\System32`, but the `OpenSSH` folder does not exist. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 64-bit version of PowerShell ISE (and `cmd.exe` and Windows File Explorer) and 32-bit version PowerShell (or vice versa – unlikely).

The `System32` folder has two versions, one for 32-bit applications and one for 64-bit applications. Read about [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector).

The `OpenSSH` folder probably exists only in one of these versions on your system (probably the 64-bit one). Currently I have `OpenSSH` in both versions. But I remember that not so long before I had `OpenSSH` in 64-bit version only – So it got possibly resolved by some recent Windows update.

Comment: That worked...I simply changed the path on my shortcut to the powershell version in the system32 folder and now ssh works there too...thank you.  I tried to upvote, but I guess I am too new for it to display.